# HTML how delete tag but not content

Tags: javascript, html, dom

how can I delete with javascript html tag (for example span) but not the content and the html tags in the content?
one example:

```
<div id="content">
    <span id=1 class="note" >
        <p>   <span id=1 class="note" >hello! its one example  </span> </p>
        <li>  <span id=1 class="note" >yes,one example  </span> </li>
    </span> 
</div>
```

the result should be:

```
<div id="content">
    <p> hello! its one example</p><li>yes,one example</li>
</div>
```

Comment: html may have more span with class="note"

Comment: I do not want to use jqueri unless strictly necessary

Comment: Would modifying the PHP be an option? That would allow you to remove the spans before they're ever displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 5):

Since you haven't mentioned that you need JQuery, following is the code that I propose:

http://jsfiddle.net/9qgK7/

Relevant code:

```
span.outerHTML = span.innerHTML;
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML
PS: Firefox only started supporting `outerHTML` since v11 but we are already using v15 :)

Comment: is compatible with other browsers? IE,Chrome,Opera??

Comment: Already mentioned in the end of the msdn page provided: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML#Browser_compatibility Firefox was the last to support it.

Comment: it is good answer, this really works. It is inefficient,thanks anyway!

Comment: @Martin, can you tell me why this code is inefficient? It would help me in understanding JavaScript. From what I see, I provided a basic example and you couldn't even convert it to use in your "new example".

Comment: Sorry if I offended you :). I think it is inefficient because every time that you call getSpans() you  have to re-search all types span. But it is my opinion.

Comment: this solution is simple, but if you used to have a reference to some of the inner elements, they will become invalid :(  as basically the browser will reinterpret the new html you've set, and recreate nodes out of it

Answer (score 3):

In your particular example, its probably best practice to just overwrite the immediate *parentNode*.

```
var content  = document.getElementById('content'),
    span     = content.getElementsByTagName('span')[0],
    p        = content.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

content.innerHTML = span.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery, try something like this

```
var newContent = $("#content span").html();
$("#content").html(newContent);
```

**EDIT**

Pure JS solution

```
var spans = document.getElementById("content").getElementsByClassName("note");
var out = "";

for (var i = spans.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  out += spans[i].innerHTML;
}
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = out;
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cvm7K/1/)

Comment: I do not want to use jqueri unless strictly necessary

Comment: I've added a pure JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 1):

Can easily be done with Jquery:

```
$('span.note').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: I do not want to use jqueri unless strictly necessary